# Allocation of the available computational resources

Tags: concept

I am trying to figure out solution for a problem. We have some computation resources available at our disposal - A machine with 48 GB RAM, 1 1080 Ti GPUs, 1TB SSD. We want to allocate these resources for projects in a company. How to figure out which project should be given higher priority in a given scenario.

Company gets a request to improve the efficiency of a deep learning solution for a existing client, who is a valued customer.

In parallel, it receives got another task which involve completing a Proof Of Concept, involving deep learning,for a prospective client.

Both tasks may consume all available resources.

Hard Constraints - Use the on-premise computation resources only.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to run [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) and manage the pods. This allows virtualization of your servers, network, services, databases etc., and allows tight packing.

You can run Kubernetes on you on-prem infrastructure.

Bit of a steep learning curve, but gives you full control.

As an aside, I am assuming this computational resource is an investment for speeding up projects and not the production hardware. For production, you may want separation of concerns. So, packing a lot on the same hardware might introduce risks (when one department/subsystem's modules misbehave, it risks impacting others negatively). Yes, virtualization is supposed to prevent it and by and large, it does. But software is not perfect and the risk is not zero. So, keep that in mind as well.

**Reading material:**

[Kubernetes Basics](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is quite helpful.